# Application of Taylor's theorem to approximate $f(x)=\sin x$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Show that $f(x)=\sin x$, $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ can be approximated by $x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ with an error less than $\frac{1}{400}$.

Using Taylor's theorem I can write $$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+R_5$$where $R_5=\frac{x^5}{5!}f^{5}(c)<\frac{(\frac{\pi}{4})^5}{5!}$, which is nearly equal to  $\frac{1}{400}$, but how to get it from $R_5$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! We have $\frac{(\frac{\pi}{4})^5}{5!} < \frac1{400}$, which means that
$$
|R_5|=\left|\frac{x^5}{5!}f^{5}(c)\right|<\frac{(\frac{\pi}{4})^5}{5!}<\frac1{400}\\
|R_5|<\frac1{400}
$$

Comment: how $\frac{(\frac{\pi}{4})^5}{5!} < \frac1{400} $ ?

Comment: Note that the requirement is that $|R_5|<1/400$ and not only that $R_5<1/400$.

Comment: @ArunBadajena Because $\frac{(\frac{\pi}{4})^5}{5!} \approx 0.00249$, and $\frac{1}{400} = 0.0025$.

Comment: @skyking You're right, but it's not difficult to insert absolute value signs everywhere here.

Comment: Yes, but I think you should

Comment: @Arthur you mean by direct calculation? I wanted to know can we go from $\frac{(\frac{\pi}{4})^5}{5!}$ to $ \frac1{400}$?

Comment: @ArunBadajena Yes, I mean direct calculation. The margins are so small (less than half a percent) that I don't think there is an easy way. If there had been logarithms or exponents or roots, then maybe, but $\pi$ has no inherent arithmetic / algebraic properties to exploit.

Comment: The calculation would be possibly to  do by hand by using that $\pi<22/7$.